# Have we independently verified Leavitt’s luminosity-period relationship?

Tags: optics, astrophysics, astronomy

After Henrietta Leavitt discovered the relationship between luminosity period amongst cephids in the Magellanic Clouds, how was she so sure that you can extend this relationship to other Cepheids stars in other places? This is the part I’m confused because how do we know that these stars are the same to use this principle? Now with other instruments that can allow us to measure further out, have we somehow independently tested that using leavitt’s law truly works? It seems like we are assuming ALL this Cepheid stars are the same based on their periods. Im sorry if it doesn’t make since, I’m learning

Comment: On what basis do you think variable stars in one region of the universe would behave differently to those in another region?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @josephh If stars are different, isn’t it wrong to use one star’s luminosity to measure the distance of other? Aren’t we assuming that ALL cepheid stars are the same so it hold the same luminosity -period relationship? How can this be verified?

Comment: @josephh Because they have different chemical compositions.

Comment: @ProfRob That’s not what the op is asking. Op assumes two stars of the same type will behave differently depending on _where_ they are in the universe. This cannot be true if we agree the universe is homogeneous, isotropic etc. (and most physicists do). Unless you mean a star type will have a different composition depending on where it is in the universe? How do you justify this?

Comment: The P-L relationships in the low-metallicity Magellanic clouds are different to those in the Milky Way or M31. I.e. different in two differing places @josephh  On the scales where Cepheid distances are useful, the universe isn't homogeneous and it is *well known* that different galaxies have differing average compositions.

Answer (score 1):

The distance to many Galactic Cepheids are now known from their trigonometric parallaxes (from Gaia), thus independently arriving at a period-luminosity relationship (e.g., [Groenewegen 2018](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/abs/2018/11/aa33478-18/aa33478-18.html), [Clementine et al. 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.02079), [Molinaro et al. 2023](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2023MNRAS.520.4154M/abstract)).

In principle this also allows some measurement of the metallicity dependence. Indeed, the Leavitt law cannot be thoughtlessly applied across populations with composition very different to the calibration sample and the period-luminosity law has a different slope and intercept for populations with different metallicity ([Romaniello et al. 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1196); [Ripepi et al. 2020](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2020/10/aa38714-20/aa38714-20.html#:%7E:text=Classical%20Cepheids%20(DCEPs)%20are%20the,Hubble%20constant%20(H0).)). The differences are probably bigger in the V band than at near infrared wavelengths. This means that Cepheids in the Magellanic clouds, where Leavitt's work was done, that have lower metallicity than Cepheids in the Milky Way or M31, do obey somewhat *different* period-luminosity relationships.